# Issue while saving rects, it crash my game

Tags: python, random, pygame

I have this code that saves the position and the rect from an object (usally small, like a drawing) and then spawns them (blits) in my screen. I encountered that if I put too many objects or too big, I´m guessing the rects collide and then the game crashes, but also, sometimes, even if I have not many objects, it can crash because this occurance.

How could I solve this problem? I´m guessing adding an if sentence so it checks that is not as near as to crash the game or something like that, where I save the rects of the images is in the **for i in self.game_images:** :

```
class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self, game, images, main_image, next_scene):
        super().__init__(next_scene)
        
        self.game = game
        self.main_image = main_image
        self.game_images = images

        # Fade effect set-up
        self.fade = False
        self.fade_time = 0
        self.current_alpha = 255
        self.part = 1

        self.record_text = font.render('Atiende',True, PURPLE)
        self.correct_image_rect = None

        # Trying to use colliderect so it doesnt overlap
        # this is the same code as before but adapted to use the gameimage class and the rects stored there
        self.rects = []
        for i in self.game_images:
            position_set = False 
            while not position_set:
                x = random.randint(100,950)
                y = random.randint(100,600) 

                i.rect.x = x
                i.rect.y = y

                margin = 5
                rl = [rect.inflate(margin*2, margin*2) for rect in self.rects]
                if len(self.rects) == 0 or i.rect.collidelist(rl) < 0:
                    self.rects.append(i.rect)
                    position_set = True

        # this makes a number and object pair, and allows us to set the correct rects for the correct gameimage classes
        for i, rect in enumerate(self.rects):
            self.game_images[i].rect = rect

    # this is the fade stuff from before that was in draw. It really belongs here tbh
    def update(self, dt):
        if self.part == 1 and self.fade:
            self.fade_time += dt
            if self.fade_time > fade_timer:
                self.fade_time = 0
                self.main_image.set_alpha(self.current_alpha)
                self.record_text.set_alpha(self.current_alpha)
                # Speed whichin the image dissapears
                self.current_alpha -= 5
                if self.current_alpha <= 0:
                    self.fade = False
                    self.part = 2

        else:
            # we reset the main image alpha otherwise it will be invisible on the next screen (yeah, this one caught me out lol!)
            self.main_image.set_alpha(255)

    # draw is similar to before, but a bit more streamlined as the fade stuff is not in update
    def draw(self, screen):
        super().draw(screen)

        if self.part == 1:
            screen.blit(self.record_text, (550, 20))
            screen.blit(self.main_image.image, (580, 280)) 
        else:
            # Second half 
            text2 = font.render('¿Qué has visto?',True, PURPLE)
            screen.blit(text2, (400,5))

            # Show all similar images      
            for game_image in self.game_images:
                game_image.draw(screen)

            # We associate the correct rect to the correct image, to pass it later to the CORRECT Screen
            self.correct_image_rect = self.game_images[self.game_images.index(self.main_image)].rect

    # again we pass the event to the game object the same as with the other classes
    def get_event(self, event):
        if self.part == 2:
            if self.game.level == 13:
                self.game.game_over = True
            if self.correct_image_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                return 'CORRECT'
            for rect in self.rects:
                if not self.correct_image_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    return 'INCORRECT'
```

Comment: "the game crashes" – surely there's some error and a traceback?

Comment: I am very sure that you end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: I´m pretty new so I don´t have a traceback sorry, as for if it ends in an infinite loop, I don´t really understand what you mean, I guess you are saying it gets an infinte loop and thats why it crashes. Also I have to say that this fragment of the code is not all the code.What I understand is that it crashes because theres probably conflict between saved rects when I blitz them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You end up in an infinite loop, because you try to add all the objects at once. If the algorithm cannot find a random position for an object that does not collide with another object, the loop does not terminate.

Create the objects one by one in the `update` method. The `update` method is continuously called in the application loop. Create on object per frame. There may be times when not all objects can be generated, but you can avoid the infinite loop:

```py
class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self, game, images, main_image, next_scene):
        super().__init__(next_scene)
        
        self.game = game
        self.main_image = main_image
        self.game_images = images

        # Fade effect set-up
        self.fade = False
        self.fade_time = 0
        self.current_alpha = 255
        self.part = 1

        self.record_text = font.render('Atiende',True, PURPLE)
        self.correct_image_rect = None

        # Trying to use colliderect so it doesnt overlap
        # this is the same code as before but adapted to use the gameimage class and the rects stored there
        self.rects = []
        

    # this is the fade stuff from before that was in draw. It really belongs here tbh
    def update(self, dt):

        if len(self.rects) < len(self.game_images):
            i = len(self.rects)

            x = random.randint(100,950)
            y = random.randint(100,600) 
            
            self.game_images[i].rect.x = x
            self.game_images[i].rect.y = y

            margin = 5
            rl = [rect.inflate(margin*2, margin*2) for rect in self.rects]
            if len(self.rects) == 0 or self.game_images[i].rect.collidelist(rl) < 0:
                self.rects.append(self.game_images[i].rect)
                
        if self.part == 1 and self.fade:
            self.fade_time += dt
            if self.fade_time > fade_timer:
                self.fade_time = 0
                self.main_image.set_alpha(self.current_alpha)
                self.record_text.set_alpha(self.current_alpha)
                # Speed whichin the image dissapears
                self.current_alpha -= 5
                if self.current_alpha <= 0:
                    self.fade = False
                    self.part = 2

        else:
            # we reset the main image alpha otherwise it will be invisible on the next screen (yeah, this one caught me out lol!)
            self.main_image.set_alpha(255)

    # [...]
```